# MyEclipse - Deploy war file into tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web, war, myeclipse

I want to have a war file deployed into tomcat of MyEclipse. I tried `Add Deployment` to tomcat but it can only deploy projects of MyEclipse. Then I tried to import the war file into a project, but there is no war file option in MyEclipse import.

How can I get a war file running in MyEclipse tomcat server ?

Comment: MyEclipse is for development of J2EE projects (mainly), with deployment of those projects to servers for testing. Can you explain why you want to deploy a war file (presumably obtained via some other mechanism) to the built-in MyEclipse Tomcat? If you're not using MyEclipse for development of the Web application, then I'd suggest using a stand-alone Tomcat installation to deploy the WAR. WAR files, however, can be imported. Filter the Import wizard for "WAR". You may need to turn on WTP Extras to see it (in the preferences, general, capabilities, advanced screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want tot run war file in tomcat eclipse, you just simply place your war file to tomcat webapps folder.

Please follow the below step:

```
1) Stop Tomcat.
2) Delete existing deployment. If you have previously deployed "foo.war" in TOMCAT_HOME/webapps, then it has been unpacked into webapps/foo/... You must delete this directory and all its contents. On Unix, this can be done with
rm -r $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/foo

3) Copy WAR file to TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/.
4) Start Tomcat.
```

More documentation for such kind of problem [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html)